# Iterating over a json array of objects in Clojure

Tags: json, clojure, clojurescript, reagent

I'm going to implement a restful API using Clojure. For GET request there is a url such as `/List` and I want to return a parsed response from below pure data which is a json file.
GET request:

```
(GET "/list/:from-date/:to-date" [from-date to-date]
      wrap-json-response (response (parse-object from-date to-date all-records)))
```

As you can see it's needed to have two query parameters `from-date` and `to-date`. What I need is a function named `parse-object` that parses the pure data and compare the `update-date` to `from-date` and `to-date`. If `update-date` is between of those two parameters then returns it in expected object structure.
Below is pure object and expected object structure with given data.

Pure data (data.json):

```
[{"name": "JOHN",
  "update-date": "2017-11-10",
  "role": "admin"},
 {"name": "CHRIS",
  "update-date": "2018-04-28",
  "role": "user"},
 {"name": "ANNIE",
  "update-date": "2018-03-11",
  "role": "admin"}]
```

Given parameters: `from-date: 2017-11-01 to-date: 2018-04-28`

Expected returned response:

```
{"users":[
     {"role":"admin",
      "shows":[
            {"name":"JOHN",
             "status":"active"}]},
      {"role":"user",
       "shows":[
            {"name":"CHRIS",
             "status":"active"}]}]}
```

Comment: What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 0):

You can do JSON parsing/printing in Clojure using a library like Cheshire (https://github.com/dakrone/cheshire).

You can filter data using the `filter` function:

```
(filter (fn [{:strs [update-date]}]
          (not (or (.before update-date from-date)
                   (.after update-date to-date))))
        objects)
```

You can reshape the data using `group-by`:

```
(group-by (fn [{:strs [role]}]
            role)
          objects)
```

And using a `for` expression:

```
(for [[k xs] groups]
  {"role" k
   "shows" (for [x xs]
             (select-keys x ["name" "status"]))})
```

Comment: Sorry I'm a bit new to Clojure. I'm using data.json to deal with JSON file. How come you used *.before* and *.after* for dates even though they're string.

Comment: Hi Sepehr; I'm making the assumption here that you would parse them to java.time Instants to compare them. You could also rely just on the existing date format to do a string comparison `(compare "abc" "def")`.

Answer (score 0):

Here is an outline of how you could do it. I'll leave the final formatting to you.

```
(ns tst.demo.core
  (:use tupelo.core demo.core tupelo.test)
  (:require
    [tupelo.string :as tstr] )
  (:import [java.time LocalDate]))

(def data-json
  "[{'name' : 'JOHN',
     'update-date' : '2017-11-10',
    'role' : 'admin'},
   {'name' : 'CHRIS',
     'update-date' : '2018-04-28',
    'role' : 'user'},
   {'name' : 'ANNIE',
    'update-date' : '2018-03-11',
    'role' : 'admin'}] ")

(dotest
  (let
    [date-from (LocalDate/parse "2017-11-01")
     date-to   (LocalDate/parse "2018-04-28")
     data-edn  (json->edn (tstr/quotes->double data-json))
     data-keep (vec
                 (remove nil?
                   (for [user-rec data-edn]
                     (let [update-date (LocalDate/parse (grab :update-date user-rec))]
                       (when (and
                               (.isBefore date-from update-date)   ; may need to add .isEqual
                               (.isAfter  date-to   update-date))  ; may need to add .isEqual
                         user-rec)))))]
    (spyx-pretty data-keep)))
```

with results:

```
---------------------------------------------
   Clojure 1.10.0-alpha8    Java 1.8.0_161
---------------------------------------------

Testing tst.demo.core
data-keep => 
[{:name "JOHN",  :update-date "2017-11-10", :role "admin"}
 {:name "ANNIE", :update-date "2018-03-11", :role "admin"}]
```